# EWS emails with HTML BodyType

Tags: html, xml, email, exchangewebservices

I have an application that periodically polls an 2010 exchange server email inbox for emails with a certain subject.

I am using c#, .Net 3.5 in VS2008. I can successfully connected to, retrieve all the emails I require.

If the Body of the email contains XML which is validated with an xsd, usually this is working fine but when the email has a BodyType of HTML the xml tags are not displayed and it fails the xsd validation.

If I do a show source on the email body the xml tags are all there. My question is, how do I get the actual xml text and not the html text?
I initiate the service using

```
m_Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
```

I am returning the search results using this...

```
public void getEmails(string searchType)
{
   ItemView itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
   SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailSubject);
   SearchResults = Service.FindItems(GetFolderName(searchType), searchFilter, itemView);
}
```

and loading the individual emails

```
foreach (Item item in SearchResults)
{
    item.Load();
    EmailMessage mes = (EmailMessage)item;
    string emailBody = item.Body.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to get PR_HTML MAPI property. You can added as extended property in your request. It works with [Exchange Web Services .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices), but should also work with EWS Managed API

Comment: Please add more details